# Excel formula to get certain cell if the value is between 2 numbers

Tags: excel, matrix, formula

In the left there is the table i have, in the right the desired output

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BZeM.png)

I tried with the following function but only works if the values in D and E are in the same column (E) one under the other

=IF(AND(G1>=$E$3:$E$10;G1<=$E$3:$E$10);"No match!";INDEX($D$3:$D$10;IF.ERROR(MATCH(G1;$E$3:$E$10);1)))

Answer (score 1):

So, first with vlookup():

[image]

Formula so you can copy & paste:

```
VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$5,2,1)
```

For those who think vlookup() is a poor choice, here is the use of index() with match(), which needs more typing and no benefit in this situation:

```
INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$5,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly. Is it a number in C column is your desired output depended on range described in D and E columns? If yes then you cat try:

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$9,($D$2:$D$9<=G2)*($E$2:$E$9>=G2),)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($D$2:$D$9<=G2)*(--($E$2:$E$9>=G2)),$C$2:$C$9)
```

Change separators `,` to `;` if needed.

Result:
[image]