# Getting "Too many functions" in Excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am writing a formula for Excel. Excel says that I entered too many arguments. Am I missing any brackets or my formula is wrong?

`10000+IF(AND(F5>=98%, (D17-D125)>0),((D5*2.5)+(0.2*(D17-D125))),(D5*2.5),IF(AND(98%>F5,F5>=90%,(D17-D125)>0),((D5*1.5)+(0.1*(D17-D125))),(D5*1.5),IF(AND(90%>F5,F5>=80%,(D17-D125)>0),((D5*0.5)+(0.05*(D17-D125))),(D5*0.5),IF(AND(F5<80%),(D17-D125)>0),((D5*0)+(0*(D17-D125))),(D5*0))))`

Is there any shorter formula to use?

Comment: Well, one cell with the calculation of d17-D125, then a table of data (2 columns) for the values of F5 and the results. Then the calculation can be =10000+vlookup(). That's the basic structure.

Comment: Please show me how that will go in a formula.

Comment: This formula with all of these conditions can just show in one cell. I cannot include or create other cells.

Comment: ((D50)+(0*(D17-D125)) is meant to be 0 yes? given that the * is converting to *italic*

Comment: 10000+IF(AND(F5>=98%, (D17-D125)>0),((D5*2.5)+(0.2*(D17-D125))),(D5*2.5),IF(AND(98%>F5,F5>=90%,(D17-D125)>0),((D5*1.5)+(0.1*(D17-D125))),(D5*1.5),IF(AND(90%>F5,F5>=80%,(D17-D125)>0),((D5*0.5)+(0.05*(D17-D125))),(D5*0.5),IF(AND(F5<80%),(D17-D125)>0),0))). I tried it this way and still said too many arguments.

Comment: So probably means you have a bracket in the wrong place. However I did show you an alternative.

Comment: Your `IF` functions have four arguments. If you break it down, it looks like `=1st_IF(condition, result if true, result if false, 2nd_IF(condition, result if true, result if false,3rd_IF(... `  You are just chaining your `IF` statements. Not the correct syntax. You also have way too many parentheses which add to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

So, quick example to show how vlookup() works, Excel has good examples in the Function Reference. vlookup() can have all the arguments built-in so only one cell needed. Just shown it like this to show.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$7:$B$11,2,1)
```

[image]

Comment: The above does not work in my case. Thank you. I just wanted to know why my formula is not working.

Comment: Not sure why you think it won't work in your case. I used 5 vlookup() in one formula to interpolate values from a table - worked a treat.

Comment: Here you can see a version using index() with match(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/75413144/4961700

Comment: Believe me it will not work in my situation because I need to aplly more than 7 conditions as shown in my formula above. Can we use ifs instead? and I tried it but it gave the wrong results.

Comment: Sorry I don’t believe you. I tell my students to avoid using if() more that 3 levels deep as you get lost in the logic *so* easily - as you demonstrate. I have done one grading expression with 10 levels but took 3 cups of coffee and over an hour. Did it with vlookup() and a table in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your intentions are mathematically, and it definitely seems like theres a simple solution here. But when analyzing your formula.. I had trouble almost instantly when breaking it up into a more procedural If/then/else structure.. So you do have misplaced parens, extra parameters to IF(), etc.

I really like the LET() function to setup variable names or simply to avoid repeating myself. And then since you're chaining IFs, just use IFS() instead..

LET() works like LET(name1, value1, name2, value2, result).

IFS() works like IFS(condition1, resultIf1, condition2, resultIf2)

Something like the following is at least easier on the eyes..

```
LET(
    VarA, F5,
    VarB, D17-D125,
    VarC, D5,
    VarD, VarB > 0,
    IFS(
        AND(VarA > 98%, VarD), D5*2.5,
        AND(VarA < 98%, VarA >= 90%, VarD), D5*1.5 + 0.1*VarB,
        AND(VarA < 90%, VarA >= 80%, VarD), D5*0.5 + 0.5*VarB,
        ...
        TRUE, default value
    )
)
```

Comment: What do I need to put in the default value? It did not work for me.

Comment: 98%    $50  $60   $10 
    
    
if A2>=98%, and (60-50)>0, then $200 + 3.5*$10+0.2*(60-50)    
if A2 between 98% and 90% and (60-50)>0, then $200 + 2.5*$10+0.1*(60-50)    
if A2 between 90% and 80% and (60-50)>0, then $200 + 1.5*$10+0.05*(60-50)    
if A2 < 80%  and (60-50)>0, then $200 + 0*$10+0*(60-50)

Comment: the last condition.. if none of those are true

Comment: Excel returned an error. It did not accept the "F5". I think I am supposed to add a number or text. I cannot add a cell number.

Comment: something like..
```
LET(
 VarA, F5,
 VarB, D17-D125,
 VarC, D5,
 VarD, VarB > 0,
 IFS(
  AND(VarA > 98%, VarD), 200 + 3.5*VarC + 0.2*VarB,
  AND(VarA < 98%, VarA >= 90%, VarD), 200 + 2.5*VarC + 0.1*VarB,
  AND(VarA < 90%, VarA >= 80%, VarD), 200 + 1.5*VarC + 0.05*VarB,
  AND(VarA < 80%, VarD), 200 + 0*VarC + 0*VarB
 )
)
```

Comment: since i dont know what you're trying to do exactly, i cant give you a formula that is 100% correct.. you're going to have to substitute the things you are working with